Using Barcode with node.js
I am using a barcode module (npm i barcode) from NPMJS to generate a barcode on the fly, however, after following the instructions I get res is not defined and no barcode, could some one point me in the right direction... this is my code
// Generate Barcode
const barcode = require('barcode');
const code39 = barcode('code39', {
    data: "BARCODE DATA",
    width: 400,
    height: 125,
});

// Fancy ass barcode
code39.getBase64(function (err, imgsrc) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // if we're using HTTP or another framework
  res.end('<img src="' + imgsrc + '">');
});

I tried the devs own website for help, GitHub, Google and stackOverflow.
I need this for a PoC so any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE:
So this isn't being done in Express, I'm running it as part of a node script... I'll find another module...

Here's a pointer: res is most likely a parameter of an express.js middleware function. Do you use express.js in your code?

"res is not defined" - Indeed it isn't.  Where do you expect it to have been defined?  What are you expecting that line of code to do and why?  What specific result are you attempting to produce?

The "if we're using HTTP or another framework" from the example indicates that it's from the HTTP lib.

As a guess... Did you just want to output imgsrc to the console instead?

The barcode NPM package shows this in there Usage documentation:

Base64 encoded img src
Often times, barcodes are single use for a single print or whatever. With this method, we can create one on the fly and just send the base64 encoded image to the browser through the HTML.
code39.getBase64(function (err, imgsrc) {
    if (err) throw err;
 
    // if we're using HTTP or another framework
    res.end('<img src="' + imgsrc + '">');
});


This is just an example on how you could send an base64 encoded value. The examples uses res, which is part of the HTTP NPM package. It's not needed, it's just an example.


I get res is not defined and no barcode, could some one point me in the right direction... this is my code

If you just need a barcode for your PoC, the barcode function will already create the barcode, it's up to you what you're going to do with it.
// Generate Barcode
const barcode = require('barcode');
const code39 = barcode('code39', {
    data: "BARCODE DATA",
    width: 400,
    height: 125,
});

// Log base64 barcode to console
code39.getBase64(function (err, imgsrc) {
    console.log(imgsrc);
});

